# Magic Lantern equivalent for Nikon or Panasonic?

Tags: nikon, panasonic-lumix, firmware, magic-lantern

I am very interested in a specific use case for either the Nikon Coolpix B700 or the Panasonic LUMIX FZ80 because of 4k video and super zoom (and the fact that they are crazy cheap). However, the lack of live output via HDMI/other is quite frustrating. I need to be able to view video remotely.

Is there something like Magic Lantern that targets either of those manufacturers?

Comment: For Nikon DSLRs there's [Nikon Patch](https://nikonhacker.com/wiki/Supported_Models), but that doesn't support the Coolpix line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Panasonic camera (if you have a tablet or smart phone) you could download imageapp https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.panasonic.avc.cng.imageapp&hl=en_GB which allows remote access/control to the camera

Comment: Found it in the Apple app store, works on both iphone and ipad. On the ipad, it has a nice landscape mode where the preview of the camera's view is nice and big. Thanks

Comment: Great news @Roger! It's also great for sneaky "street" pictures. I put my camera on a tripod in a good photo location and look busy on my tablet while taking images without  folk being aware!

Answer (score 2):

Though the models specified in this question are not supported, however:

Nikon: http://nikonhacker.com/

Panasoinc: http://www.gh1-hack.info/

source: https://www.digitaltrends.com/photography/camera-firmware-hacks/